# jquery mobile, how do I eliminate top white edge on icons, but keep on buttons

Tags: jquery, mobile

I can't seem to eliminate the top white edge that appears on icon art. I do want to keep the top white edge on the jquery mobile buttons. I can't seem to effect it with css. Here is the URL to see the problem:

http://www.wildwoodsnj.com/m/nav2.cfm

Answer (score 0):

Add `.ui-bar-a{ border:0 !important; }` to the top of the file.

**Edit:**
Sorry, I see that you'd like to keep the top white edge on the main links, but not the icons.  Try this.

```
span.ui-btn-inner { border:0 !important; }
```

Comment: You're welcome, good luck with the rest of the build!  And welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

try background: none; or outline: none;